# Exporting data to excel from grid

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am exporting data from WPF datagrid to an excel worksheet in my application. Here is the code snippet i arrived at.

```
dgDisplay.SelectAllCells();
dgDisplay.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dgDisplay);
//String resultat = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
dgDisplay.UnselectAllCells();
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports\\SampleReport.xls";
System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@path);
file1.WriteLine(result.Replace(',', ' '));
file1.Close();
```

Now the excel file is created fine with expected data. But on opening via code or by using excel. i get the below warning when opening

[image]

Though there might be other reasons for a similar error frome excel this one i think is due to the below 2 lines

```
String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
```

This changes the format. If i select Yes to proceed and open it gives me the correct data.
I have been trying to figure out a way so that the data generated is same but does not pop a warning for changed format. Please suggest ?

Comment: The issue has to do more with uploading data to excel from C# code than wpf or winforms so hence adding both the tags to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **.xls**-extension you give your file is reserved for the binary Excel (BIFF8) format. You are saving a delimited text-file, which should have the extension **.csv**. Try to change the file-name and it should work.

If you want to generate a file in the properitary, binary Excel format you have to do manual work and use a library, e.g. [ExcelLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/).

Comment: If i change it to a csv and all the data populate into column 1. when i had it as an xls all the data were populating into 4 columns as expected.

Comment: Try to omit the Replace of commas with spaces in the WriteLine statement. Just write `result`

Comment: Perhaps you can post the contents of the resulting csv/xls file you get in your question.

Comment: Wait i see what is happening now. String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text); . Since i am using result   i should have had String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);. And then everything is fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write simple text to an Excel `.xlsx` file.

Option 1: You write a `.csv` file and open that in Excel.

Option 2: You use a libraby to write correct `.xlsx` files, e.g. [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me. Updating as asked.

```
private void StartCreatingReport(DataGrid dgDisplay)
    {

        dgDisplay.SelectAllCells();
        dgDisplay.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dgDisplay);
        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);           
        dgDisplay.UnselectAllCells();

        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Reports\\SampleReport.csv";



        System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@path);

        file1.WriteLine(result);
        file1.Close();
    }
```

I pass any grid that has to be exported to excel to this method. I also place a csv file in path (SampleReport.csv in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I use the code, but each line is stored in one cell (A1) with comma separting each fields

but When i use GetData(DataFormats.Text), every field has one column, but before Excel show it warning.